# Non-conforming grid-lines in a grid-system

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

In my, relatively, simple grid, I'm trying to setup "non-conforming" cells/grid-lines (in lack of better phrasing).

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="b"></td>
    <td class="c"></td>
    <td class="d">Text</td>
    <td class="e"></td>
    <td class="f">
      <button>Btn</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS grid:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    height: 200px;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 70% 30%;
}

.a {
    grid-row: 1;
    background: green;
}

.b {
    grid-row: 1;
    background: blue;
}

.c {
    grid-row: 1;
    background: red;
}

.d {
    grid-row: 1;
    background: darkmagenta;
}

.e {
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    background: gray;
}

.f {
    grid-column: 4;
    background: purple;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zp1s3ca5/

This gives me:

[image]

However, I need to have cell `d` be **less** in height, and cell `f` be **more**.

Like this:

[image]

I can't seem to "break" the row lines. How do I do this?

PS: I thought about rowspanning cell `d` + `f`, and setting up another grid within that one cell. The problem is, I need to re-arrange the cells on mobile view (with cell `d` going up top, and cell `f` going at the bottom), and so I can't see how that would work.

Comment: HTML tables should not be implemented with display: grid. If you can come up with an HTML structure that is more amenable to grid layout, you can simply have the magenta-purple area be a single grid item spanning both rows, with its own block or flex layout independent of the grid.

Comment: I should probably have clarified: I need the <table> to be grid for js sorting reasons -- while at the same time only allowing for ONE <tr> per "listing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created two rows for your grid container:

```
grid-template-rows: 70% 30%;
```

This is the limit you've set for creating grid areas.

Instead, create many more rows, then span your grid areas as necessary. This gives you more flexibility. The more rows you create, the more precise your grid areas can be. Try this:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 10%);
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

tr {
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  height: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 10%); /* ADJUSTMENT */
}

.a {
  grid-row: 1 / span 7;
  background: green;
}

.b {
  grid-row: 1 / span 7;
  background: blue;
}

.c {
  grid-row: 1 / span 7;
  background: red;
}

.d {
  grid-row: 1 / span 5;
  background: yellow;
}

.e {
  grid-row: 8 / span 3;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  background: gray;
}

.f {
  grid-row: 6 / span 5;
  grid-column: 4;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td class="b"></td>
    <td class="c"></td>
    <td class="d">Text</td>
    <td class="e"></td>
    <td class="f"><button>Btn</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zp1s3ca5/3/)

Comment: Ah yes of course, logical thinking. Somehow escaped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another row `grid-template-rows: 60% 10% 30%;` - break the 70% however you desire.
and then color the div you want to change with the color of the div you want to expand.

check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zp1s3ca5/8/)